# Hook into Spotlight

Tags: spotlight

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to include custom results in the Spotlight search. Our organization has an external page for looking up certain data and I want to be able to include these results in the spotlight search results. Is this possible? Otherwise, is this something that a 3rd party tool could be configured for?

Comment: Just to add to this, I am able to code the solution. I'm not looking for a pre built package that will just do this for me. i'm interested if the API is available etc

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 9 this year, Apple completely revamped Spotlight Search and now there are way better APIs available to developers.

If you want this to appear to public users, you can look at the new Web Markup.

If you only want people in your organization to be able to see these results this is what I would do. If you have an app that people at your organization use I would simply add some code to periodically check for results and use the CoreSpotlight API to add them into Spotlight. You could handle the website in your app, or make it take them to Safari when the result is tapped. If you do not have an app you would have to create one and give it to your users (slightly less convienient).